# C++  client-server app

Tags: rpc, клиент-сервер, c++

Здравствуйте! Хочу написать клиент серверное приложение, на подобии некого приложения для хранения своих заметок. На сервере простая работа с базой,  клиентом выступает десктопное приложение и андроид приложение. В каком формате лучше всего хранить данные на клиенте, xml или же хранить в sqlite базе? Какой протокол и либу лучше всего использовать для сериализации и rpc? Думаю писать все в QT, может есть что-то получше в данном случае? Спасибо заранее за советы!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> В каком формате лучше всего хранить данные на клиенте, xml или же хранить в sqlite базе?

лучше в sqlite базе. На будущее будет меньше проблем. xml для подобного не подходит. (как минимум тормознее, выборку делать сложнее).

> Какой протокол и либу лучше всего использовать для сериализации и rpc?

попробуйте json с rest. На андроиде куча библиотек, для Qt5 уже есть встроенный json.

> Думаю писать все в QT, может есть что-то получше в данном случае?

вполне нормально для декстопа, можно и сервер на базе QtCore сделать, вот только на андроиде лучше писать на java.

Comment: Не могли бы вы скинуть ссылку на толковую статью или документацию по написанию веб сервиса на QT + json rest, мне не удалось найти что-то внятное, большое спасибо заранее. И что можете сказать об Axis2c?

Comment: Вам нужно отдельно рассмотреть json и как делать сервера на qt - [статья на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/131472/).